# Why cannot i visit my ocsigen site?

Tags: ocaml, ocsigen

```
%yaourt -Qi ocaml-ocsigenserver
name　　　： ocaml-ocsigenserver
version　　： 2.0.2-1
URL　： http://ocsigen.org/

%cat ocsigen.conf.qachina
...
<ocsigen>
<server>
    <port>8000</port>
    <logdir>/media/E/RnD/ocaml/test/log/</logdir>
    <datadir>/media/E/RnD/ocaml/test/data</datadir>

    <user>***</user>
    <group>***</group>

    <charset>utf-8</charset>
    <findlib path="/usr/lib/ocaml"/>

    <extension findlib-package="ocsigenserver.ext.staticmod"/>
    <extension findlib-package="ocsigenserver.ext.cgimod">
        <cgitimeout value="30"/>
    </extension>

    <host charset="utf-8" hostfilter="*">
        <site path="ocsigenstuff">
            <static dir="/srv/ocsigenserver/ocsigenstuff" />
        </site>

        <site path="qachina">
           <cgi regexp="cgi-bin/([^/]*)" dir="/media/E/www/qachina/cgi-bin/" script="\1" />
           <static dir="/media/E/www/qachina" />
       </site>

       <static dir="/srv/ocsigenserver" />
    </host>
</server>
</ocsigen>

%ocsigen -c ocsigen.conf.qachina
```

When visiting http://127.0.0.1:8000, it works great! However, no matter visiting http://127.0.0.1:8000/ocsigenstuff or http://127.0.0.1:8000/qachina, it reports 404 error!

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: I would ask that on some `ocsigen` mailing list or forum. Last time (a year ago) when I tried `ocsigen` I noticed that the parsing of the configuration file don't give sensible error messages.

Comment: Did you try running ocsigen with -V option?

Comment: The "-V" is very helpful. It tells us that ocsigen need "index.html" not "index.htm".  After changing it to index.html, all works great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your config file. Ocsigen is looking for "index.html" in the directory, but you provided "index.htm", so it returns a "page not found" error.

As Stéphane pointed out, such a problem can be discovered by running ocsigen using the -V option.